# Parallax scrolling text with Superscrollorama

Tags: jquery, parallax

I'm trying to get John Polacek's Superscrollorama jQuery plugin to work the parallax effect on some text but I keep running into the difficulties with - error message: "controller is not defined" but as far as I can tell the controller is defined, I'm probably missing the obvious but I'm not sure what?

http://jsfiddle.net/RPRzW/6/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the controller, like so..

```
var controller = $.superscrollorama(); //Pass settings if any
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/RPRzW/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Robin, it's close but now I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addTween' "

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork: Glad it helped. I myself have just started experimenting with this plugin :)

Comment: It's a very cool plugin, I think it will help the look of my portfolio (when I get it done), I just wish they would make it easier for none programer types like me to implement.

Comment: @a_knife_a_fork: Do leave a link to your implementation in the comments. Might come in handy :)